# Do Iwahori-Hecke algebras come from cohomology classes?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras

Let $W$ be a Coxeter group. The [Iwahori-Hecke algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwahori%E2%80%93Hecke_algebra) $H_q(W)$ is a deformation of $k W$.

> **Question:**  is there some way to interpret the deformation $H_q(W)$ as a cohomology class? It doesn't seem like $kW$ twisted by a class in $H^2(W,k^{\times})$...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in an interesting way.  Cohomology classes describe formal deformations (i.e. deformations over an Artinian ring, or more generally complete local rings), and the Iwahori-Hecke algebra is trivial on a formal neighborhood of $q=1$.  In fact, the only points where it is not trivial on a formal neighborhood is when $q$ is a root of unity of small order.